# ¿Como concatenar comillas simples adentro de echo? (En php)

Tags: php

se me presentó este problema, intenté con unos ejemplos que tenía pero no funciona, es algo simple, pero que en manuales de php, y ejemplos que tenía no logré que funcione, necesito usar las comillas simples adentro de un echo:

```html
<php 

echo     '<div class="snipcart-details ">
   <form action="https://link.com" method="post">
     <button class="button w3l-cart" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://link.com', '_blank');">Ver</button>
 </form>
</div>';
```

Comment: No veo ninun echo en tu codigo

Comment: si agregas el código PHP que usas para localizar el echo que dices, va a ser mas imple que te ayudemos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que escapar las comillas con backslash `\` asi:

```
<php 
echo '<div class="snipcart-details ">
    <form action="https://link.com" method="post">
        <button class="button w3l-cart" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:window.open(\'https://link.com\', \'_blank\');">Ver</button>
    </form>
</div>';
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó, como es eso? Va una \ antes de la comillas?

Comment: Correcto el simbolo \ le dice a PHP que no es el final de tu cadena, sino que quieres incluir el siguiente simbolo en tu cadena.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no esta bien formulada porque en verdad no sabemos que quieres hacer.

si quieres concatenar una texto entre comillas en un echo:

```
 <?php
echo 'Este texto '.'y este también irán unidos';

//También puedes colocar comillas con el o sin el texto

echo '"Este texto unido'.' '.'con este saldrá entre comillas"';

//si la quieres simple, solo invierte las comillas, aunque en lo general las comillas,

echo "'este es un texto con comillas simples "."unido a otro'";

?>
```